# Model structure

Tags: sql, codeigniter, data-structures, model

i need help with writing database model for codeigniter. I have 2 tables. In First I have saved all products and in Second table I have ID of protuct and ID of category in which is. So, for example:

table **products**

```
t-shirt with ID 1
polo shirt with ID 2
```

table **categories**

```
shirts with ID 5
```

table **protucts_cat**

```
protuct_id category_id
----------  -----------
1       5
2       5
```

How can i write model to get all products with their informations, with using table `protucts_cat` and get it with `->result()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to write complicated queries without AR but you can do it with AR:

```
return $this->db->query('
    SELECT
        products.id AS product_id,
        products.name AS product_name,
        categories.id AS category_id,
        categories.name AS category_name
    FROM
        products_cat

    LEFT JOIN
            products
        ON
            products.id = products_cat.product_id

    LEFT JOIN
            categories
        ON
            categories.id = products_cat.category_id

    WHERE categories.id = '.$category_id.'
')->result();
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to write that i want only select products from one category, for example: http://example.com/category/5/ and I want to select only products that have category_id with id 5 in table protucts_cat

Comment: @Geril added where statement to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that every product is mapped to a category i would do a simple join using **active records** :

```
$this->db->select('product.id as product_id, product.name as name, categories.name')
$this->db->from('product p');
$this->db->join('protucts_cat pc','pc.product_id = p.id');
$this->db->join('categories c','c.id = pc.id');
$query = $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows){
return $query->result();
}
return false;
```